# How to clear and add new texts to a dynamically created TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have added a `TextView` dynamically in a loop. On a button click, I want to clear the existing text in the text view and set some other text to it. How can I do this?

This is my current code:

```
ArrayList<String> Cheif_ComplaintNew = new ArrayList<String>();
int cc_Arraylist_length = Cheif_ComplaintNew.size();
android.widget.TextView cc_new  = new android.widget.TextView(getApplicationContext());

for(int i=0; i<cc_Arraylist_length; i++)
{
    cc_new.setId(i);
    cc_new.setText(Cheif_ComplaintNew.get(i)); 
    cc_new.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    cc_new.setTypeface(null,android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC);
    cc_new.setTextSize(14);
    cc_linearNew.addView(cc_new);
    System.out.println("id"+i);
}
```

On a button click, the list is cleared and new data is stored in it. I want to display the new data in the same text view by clearing the old one.

Comment: You just need to store IDs of dynamic generated TextViews in int Array.

Comment: Try this: `TextView tV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
tV.setText("");` <- Set the text to whatever you want, the "" are used to clear the field.

Comment: remove all textview layouts from Main layout using linearlayout1.removeAllViewsInLayout() and create again.

Answer (score 1):

You can either add the text to the textbox when you are creating it or assign it a class variable when you create it and later on you can add text to it.

```
 TextView dynamicTextView;

 ...

 private void CreateNewTextView()
 {
     dynamicTextView = Your New Text View;
 }
 ...
 private void ChangeTheText()
 {
     dynamicTextView.SetText("new value");
 }
```

if you have more than one TextView you can create a class level generic list of TextViews and add them to the list and call them later.

you can also create a map of all TextView so you can call them with their key as well.

Comment: Mmm are u sure that storing list of views here is good idea? Map with keys.. what map ? just ids and then get it from parant view or dirrectly from activity.

Comment: Map is like a dictionary in c# you can assign a key to your values which in this case is a TextView. This method is much faster than going through all children of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set a tag to `cc_new` before add it to `cc_linearNew`, like this: `cc_new.setTag(i)`. when button got click, you can find those TextView by `cc_linearNew.findViewByTag(i)` in loop, and set new data to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many ways, some of them :

1. Store your just created ids in array. Then just get your views calling `parentView.findViewById(arreyOfIds(0));`
2. Bad for performance do not do this :) - remove all of just added views from your `parentView` and create them one more time.

To handle back click in Activity use :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
   clearTextView();
}
```

All of this will simple look like this :

```
private List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
   clearTextView();
} 

private void clearTextView()
{
   for(Integer id : ids)
   {
     TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(id);
     view.setText("")
   }
}

    private void createTextViews()
    {
                ArrayList<String>Cheif_ComplaintNew =   new ArrayList<String>   ();
                int cc_Arraylist_length=Cheif_ComplaintNew.size();
                android.widget.TextView cc_new  =   new android.widget.TextView(getApplicationContext() );

                for(int i=0; i<cc_Arraylist_length; i++)
                 {
                    ids.add(i)

                    cc_new.setId(i);
                    cc_new.setText(Cheif_ComplaintNew.get(i)); 
                    cc_new.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                    cc_new.setTypeface(null,android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC);
                    cc_new.setTextSize(14);
                    cc_linearNew.addView(cc_new);
                    System.out.println("id"+i); 

                 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how many TextViews you need to add to the layout dynamically.

As per the code mentioned, no TextViews are added to the layout as: `Cheif_ComplaintNew.size()` would return "0" so your loop will not be executed.

1. If you have to add only one TextView, then I agree with Daniel's answer of having a class level TextView variable.
2. If its multiple TextViews and you know which ID to use then in your Activity you can always get that TextView by calling `findViewById("ID_OF_THE_TEXTVIEW_NEEDED")`